# Using Commands and Hot Keys in Chrome Browser Extension

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, browser, service-worker, content-script

I'm trying to make a simple browser extension that runs a function when I use a hotkey. However, I can't get the simplest hotkey to work in the background.js file even though I feel like I've followed the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/commands/) very closely (and other tutorials).

`chrome.runtime.onInstalled` fires off toggleDark() just fine. However, the hotkey does not.

Note - I've tried a ton of different commands to make sure it wasn't just CTRL+U being overridden by another extension or browser command.

```json
 {
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "extension",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "description of the extension",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon.png",
    "48": "icon.png",
    "128": "icon.png"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icon.png",
      "24": "icon.png",
      "32": "icon.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Name of extension",
    "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
  },
  "commands": {
    "_execute_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+U",
        "mac": "Command+U"
      },
      "description": "Does a thing"
    }
  },
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "contentSettings",
    "contextMenus",
    "scripting",
    "storage"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

```js
// This works in background.js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  toggleDark();
});

// This doesn't work in background.js or popup.js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  console.log("Console log doesn't make it this far");
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    function: toggleDark,
  });
});

function toggleDark() {
  console.log("toggledark");
}
```

Note - Based on the comments below, I've tried adding the script that doesn't work to the top of my popup.js file. However, it still doesn't run.

Comment: There are no errors. Nothing happens at all. I also tried ```chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((command) => {
  console.log(`Command "${command}" called`);
});``` and it returned an type error of undefined for "onCommand"

Comment: When default_popup is defined, onClicked won't work in the background script. Put the contents of onClicked into the popup script at its beginning.

Comment: @wOxxOm so I went and dumped all of that background.js stuff after "this doesn't work" into my popup.js file. Perhaps I'm missing it in dev tools, but I'm not seeing it fire off anywhere.

Comment: Are you trying to learn about the Chrome extension API or are you trying to accomplish a custom JS task at some URLs? If the latter, you can simply write a [userscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript_manager).

Comment: Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu. Also I hope you didn't copy chrome.action.onClicked call itself.

Comment: @jsejcksn learning about the chrome ext API

Comment: @wOxxOm Yup, I have the proper dev tools open. Still appears not to be working. So bizarre. Must be something else I'm missing.

Comment: Ctrl-U is a built-in hotkey to view page source. Try a different one.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'll give that a shot right now. I've tried multiple different combinations now, including the ones listed in the Chrome dev docs.

Comment: @wOxxOm I've tried about 20 different commands. There's a chance they are all taken, but not by some obvious function that I'm aware of. Totally at a loss.

The popup as a whole works just fine. Does everything it needs to do. It's just this hot key that won't fire.

Comment: It's probably a bug, https://crbug.com/1190476. Rename _execute_action to `run` and use chrome.commands.onCommand instead of chrome.action.onClicked in the background script.

Comment: @wOxxOm oh wow! Great catch. I was going insane!